# Selecting a unique cell from a dynamic generated table

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Here goes my problem: this is the table

[image]

I want to click on delete column of a particular row say row no2  then I should select the value `OFFICED-Id` of that particular row row no.2

The problem is that table is being generated dynamically by the following code

```
<tbody>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count($detail1);$i++):?>
                      <tr>
                        <td><?=$detail1[$i]['id'];?></td>
                        <td><?=$detail1[$i]['officer_id'];?></td>
                          <td><button onclick='alert("<?=$detail1[$i]['password']?>")' > change</button></td>
                        <td><i  class=" del glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                    </tbody>
```

I am trying to select that particular cell of a row by applying this jQuery function but I am getting error in the console and it's not working too

the variable `id` is going to save that particular cell value

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".del").click(function(){
 var answer = confirm ("Are you sure you want to delete from the database?");
  var id= <?php echo $detail1[$i]['id'];?>;


  if (answer)
  {
     // your ajax code
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/del', //We are going to make the request to the method "list_dropdown" in the match controller
       data: {'id':id}, //POST parameter to be sent with the tournament id
       //With the ".html()" method we include the html code returned by AJAX into the matches list
       success: function(resp) { 
        alert('you have successfully deleted');
        },
       error: function(resp) {
         console.log('error');
        console.log(arguments);
       }
     });
  }
});
});
```

The error in the console is

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

What I figured out that this line var `id= <?php echo $detail1[$i]['id'];?>` is causing error and making my jQuery call not functioning

Is there alternative to select that particular cell OFFICED OF A ROW from a dynamic table by any event?

Comment: you need to click delete image and execute delete function??

Comment: `var id= <?php echo $detail1[$i]['id'];?>` should be `var id= '<?php echo $detail1[$i]['id'];?>'`

Comment: When I did this @PranavCBalan i got SyntaxError:`unterminated string literal var id= '

Comment: Check @PranavCBalan's comment and in `<i  class=" del glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>` define `id="del"` and in ajex use `#id`

Comment: @RaghibAhsan : sometimes the string also contains `'` that may cause problem

Comment: @Abdulla I can't give id='del' since multiple rows can't have same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var id= <?php echo $detail1[$i]['id'];?>
```

Looks like `$i` is not defined, so `id` should be null. And so the issue.

Select `id` something like this. Please test, might need extra work:

```
var id= $(this).closest('tr').find('td.id').html();
```

And HTML `<td>` of `id` line should look something like:

```
<td class="id"><?=$detail1[$i]['id'];?></td>
```

Comment: $i is defined in table for loop `<?php for($i=0;$i<count($detail1);$i++):?>` ya I too think $i is not defined inside jquey that's why I am getting null but How should I select a particular cell in this scenario when table is dynamic

Comment: @RaghibAhsan select id in jQuery itself. not php.